# X++ - Creating a CommaIO object

Tags: csv, axapta, x++

I have a simple question. When I create a CommaIO, it works but when I arrive to the 'if' statement, it doesn't go to inside the 'if'. The message 'blabla' is never printed. Nevertheless, the file name is correct and the path also. My csv files was saved in Excel with csv(comma delimited) extension. The file and directory are authorized in read mode

```
commaIO = new CommaIO(@"C:\\Users\\lbagno\\Documents\\SalesPrice.csv","r");
print "blabla";
pause;
print "fdf";
pause;

if(commaIO)
{
    print "ici3";
    pause;
}
```

Where is the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: you dont need '@' and '\\' for a start, @ makes the string literal so you can replace all your '\\' with '\', or remove the '@' from your file path

Answer (score 1):

When I first saw this I thought it was because you had \\ aswell as the @ but seemingly in my code it works when I put it in a job.

Few questions.

1. try removing the \\ so it is just \ and see whether that fixes it (as I said it doesnt make a difference on mine)
2. Does the user running AX have access to that file path?
3. Does the file exist.

A few pointers for you, try using info("string") instead of print and pause, it's more standard and you dont have to pause every step.

Also commaIO has been superceeded by CommaTextIo. Looks like you can use the same code but I'm guessing it adds some functionality. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa624902(v=ax.50).aspx

I can't comment on this post because of I don't have a high enough reputation so sorry if this isn't helpful as an answer.

Comment: Also check whether your code is running client or server side, you can use the debugger for this. The files you place on your PC will not be available from the AOS server.

Answer (score 0):

**Try moving the file to C:\Temp directory. It may be a permissions issue!!**

The `@` makes it a string literal...so you're doing double `\\` for no reason...but I think it still does work.

Use one of the two though:

```
CommaIo commaIO = new CommaIO(@"C:\Users\lbagno\Documents\SalesPrice.csv","r");
CommaIo commaIO = new CommaIO("C:\\Users\\lbagno\\Documents\\SalesPrice.csv","r");
```

Also, checking `if (commaIo)` will work if it finds a valid file, then you run `while (commaIo.status() == IO_Status::Ok)`.

I'd say the issue is that either your file does not exist (as typed), it's a client/server issue, OR it's a permissions issue.

Start with a job and a local file.